# Add icons to menu list options

Tags: android, menu

Many answers on SO would seem to suggest that it is not possible to add icons to the overflow menu list, however a number of apps, eg Contacts, (see image) have not only done just that but also have a rather nice border with rounded corners and make it appear by sliding up.  How can I do the same?  The standard menuinflater only adds icons to the action bar

[image: Contacts showing menu with icons]

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a layout for represents each option and put that with a adapater.

I do something like this:

**Layout:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayoutItem"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="left|center"
    android:paddingBottom="5sp"
    android:paddingLeft="5sp"
    android:paddingTop="5sp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/dliIVImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
        android:maxHeight="20sp"
        android:maxWidth="20sp"
        android:src="@drawable/icon" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dliLblOption"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
        android:textColor="#fff" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Adapter:**

```
    public class MenuAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private String[] options;
        private LayoutInflater mInflater;
        private ViewHolder holder;

        public static final Integer[] images = { R.drawable.icon_search,
        R.drawable.icon_profile, R.drawable.icon_password, R.drawable.icon_locate, R.drawable.icon_logout};


        static class ViewHolder{
                private TextView option;
                private ImageView img;
        }


        public MenuAdapter(Context context, String[] options) {
                mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
                this.options = options;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
                return options.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int index) {
                return options[index];
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int index) {
                return index;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int posicao, View convertView, ViewGroup arg2) {

                if (convertView == null) {
                        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_list_item, null);
                        holder = new ViewHolder();

                        holder.option = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.dliLblOption);
                        holder.img = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.dliIVImage);

                        convertView.setTag(holder);

                } else {
                        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
                }



                holder.option.setText(options[posicao]);
                holder.img.setImageResource(images[posicao]);

                return convertView;
        }

}
```

**Activity:**

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.main_activity_layout);
               opcoes = ["option1", "option2", "option3"];

                MenuAdapter mAdapter = new MenuAdapter(getApplicationContext(), opcoes);

                menuLateral = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
                listaMenuLateral = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);


                listaMenuLateral.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}
```

**Main Layout**

```
<!-- As the main content view, the view below consumes the entire
     space available using match_parent in both dimensions. -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<!-- android:layout_gravity="start" tells DrawerLayout to treat
     this as a sliding drawer on the left side for left-to-right
     languages and on the right side for right-to-left languages.
     The drawer is given a fixed width in dp and extends the full height of
     the container. A solid background is used for contrast
     with the content view. -->
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:background="#111"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for a very quick reply,  however, I'm struggling a bit.

Comment: 1.  I can't find DrawerLayout.  I thought it was in android-support-v4 but I can't find it to import it.

2.  What are R.id.drawer_layout and R.id.left_drawer

Comment: I also don't understand the code you have in the onCreate() method.  Thanks!

Comment: You can ignore the line
- menuLateral = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

In onCreate method, I've just initialize the adapter class and put that on the listview (left_drawer)